# How to read Chinese text in Latin1 encoded file in Swift

Tags: swift, string, macos, encoding

I have the following code in my macOS app that reads a latin1 encoded file:

```
let fileContent = try! String(contentsOf: pathURLOfMyFile, encoding: String.Encoding.isoLatin1)
print(fileContent)
resultTextView.string = fileContent
```

The following codes can read English code perfectly, then prints it to the console, and display it onto `resultTextView`.

But the problem is, if the file have some characters in Chinese (or I think any non-Latin character), it doesn't want to read them correctly, both the console and the text view prints random code like `ä½ å¥½` (the original text is 你好).

How can I read this file correctly in my app? Thanks.

P.S. If I change the encoding to UTF8, it will work correctly. But I have a few CSV files that can only be opened if I use the latin1 string encoding.

Here is the error when opening the file in UTF8:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=261 "The file “ExportOrderList201611182132.csv” couldn’t be opened using text encoding Unicode (UTF-8)." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/tomshen/Documents/ExportOrderList201611182132.csv, NSStringEncoding=4}: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-800.0.63/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 178
```

Comment: You are saying something inconsistent. Latin-1 cannot contain Chinese characters like `你好`. If you have some files which can only be opened in Latin-1, use Latin-1 for such files. And use UTF-8 for files containing something like `你好`.

Comment: `But I have a few CSV files that can only be opened if I use the latin1 string encoding` — What happens with them if you don't use `latin1` encoding?

Comment: @user28434 The app will freeze (or crash).

Comment: Can you replace `try!`, with `try`, wrap code in `do/catch` and add catched error's message here?

Comment: @user28434 Updated with error code while trying to open with UTF8.

Comment: @TomShen, possible related: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/47963